# Disallowing long url's in robots.txt using wildcards in between

Tags: wildcard, robots.txt

I have a situation where I need to disallow crawling on specific pages that all have the same pattern such as:

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/review
```

Where as `/folder1/folder2/folder3/` would be a listing, and adding `/review` would be what I want to disallow crawling to.

Would this line added to `robots.txt` be valid and block on the the review page and not the listing or anything else?

```
Disallow: /folder1/*/*/review
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The double * is redundant. 
A simple

> /folder1/*/review

or even

> /*/review

will do.

If you are trying to state that there **must** be a 3 folder long path before the "review" URL than I don't think you can do this is robots.txt. At least not with wildcards, beacuse * can mean any string and any number of folders.

Try using RegEx in htaccess instead.